# Creating folder with contents in project root

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I developed a tool that besides DLL requires a strong named folder with 2 files in solution. Using NuGet GUI I created the folder and populated with files, but when I install package, the only DLL created but folder with 2 files are not. How can that be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NuGet has a [set of conventions](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package) that define certain folders inside the NuGet package that will result in different actions being taken when the package is installed or uninstalled.

In order for folders to be created inside the project, when the NuGet package is installed, the folders need to be inside a **Content** directory. If you look at the jQuery package, it has a Content\Scripts folder with files inside it. This Scripts folder will be created inside your project, along with its files, when you install the jQuery NuGet package.

```
\Content
     \Scripts
         \jquery-2.1.0.js
```

Comment: At last! Oh those naming conventions! Oh them!